# Making vector curve from raster curve drawn by user

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, drawing

I'm trying to develop a simple real-time graphical editor into my web-based (flash) app. And I'm having two questions:

1. After `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN` event, I'm going to draw curve on `MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE`. After `MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP` event is dispatched drawing of a curve is stopped and I need to inform other active clients what exactly was drawn. Hence, I need to vectorize drawn curve. After that I'll replace drawn curve with vectorized. So, I'm having an array of points, and need to draw a natural curve passing through them. How can that be done?
2. I need to have an ability to erase drawn. Note that I can't use drawing with white color as erasing, as I can have image on background. What is the simpliest way to erase?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To draw vector curve, you can use [Graphics.drawPath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#drawPath%28%29) method and pass vector of points to it.
2. If you use Bitmap (BitmapData) to draw your image, you can use [copyChannel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyChannel%28%29) method, to draw your stamp of alpha brush.